# How can I match the beginning of a line in dreamweaver with regex?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Problem:
`^.+` matches only the first line of the source code in dreamweaver. I need it to match each line so that I can wrap each full line in P tags. I have 500 files to do this in.

I know `^` should match the beginning of a line and I also know that multi-line mode must be enabled for it to work on each line and not just at the beginning of the file. I also know [dreamweaver uses javascript source code](http://forums.adobe.com/message/708966#708966).

Is lack of multi-line mode the problem? Is there any way to turn it on in dreamweaver? I tried using /m at the beginning search to enable multi-line mode, but that didn't work either.

I'm open to any solution for my current problem, even if it involves a different program. However, a fix for dreamweaver is ideal, 2nd place is a way to do this in notepad++, 3rd place is a way do to this in python or something (I only know javascript, you'll have to spell it out exactly in another language).

Thank you,
robert

p.s.
I found I can "select all > right click > selection > indent" to add two spaces to the beginning of each line in dreamweaver. This allows me to find the beginning of each line with /  {2,}/. I really don't want to select all > indent on all 500 files, but i'm about to start since I've already spent a few hours bludgeoning dreamweaver.

Comment: which version of DW are you using?  P.S., you can just hit the tab key to indent your entire multiline selection...

Comment: ^^ i'm using cs4, i just didn't know that shortcut. very handy! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Dreamweaver for this - use Notepad++ (since you are familiar with it) at its regular expression support is superior.

If you are comfortable with a more robust scripting language (Python, Ruby, Perl, etc.) then that would be an ever better way to do it.

Comment: thanks andrew. initially I gave up on notepad++ because I couldn't figure out how to get part of the pattern matched to carry over into the replace. instead of using $1 like in dreamweaver, it turns out I should have used \1. so, thanks for the nudge. I didn't give notepad++ enough credit the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I might do this in DW would not involve using the find-replace tool's "Regular Expression" option, but instead using just plain old matching on a CrLf.

In the Find portion, since you can't directly enter a CrLf, you'll have to copy one to your clipboard beforehand and paste it in where needed.

In the Replace portion, replace with:

```
</p>[CrLf]
<p>
```

Again, be sure to paste in a proper "[CrLf]". This will work on all but the very first and very last lines of your document, so I know this isn't a 100% solution. There are probably better solutions using other tools that someone else can recommend!

Good luck!
-Mike

Answer (score 1):

I had a flash of insight right after posting. (isn't that the way of it?)

Dreamweaver can find the end of each line with \r\n so instead of trying to work forward, i should have just worked backwards.
search: `(.+)(\r\n)`
replace: `<p>$1</p>$2`

Answer (score 0):

`[\w\W]*` matches anything, including a newline. Its greedy, so it fact it matches everything.